# I want to write a mySQL SELECT query that eliminates rows that have duplicate values in one column

Tags: mysql

In mySQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT uID FROM table
```

returns a recordset with a single uID column where duplicate values are filtered out.

What I'm looking for is something like

```
SELECT * FROM table (and the uID column is distinct)
```

that is, where all columns are returned  *IF*  the uID value is DISTINCT

edit: here is the full table structure as requested

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (
ID int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
studyID int(10),
uID varchar(50),
---
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Please include the full table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `COUNT` here as an analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY uID) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cnt = 1;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, we can use exists logic, provided there exist another column which is always unique for each record.  Assuming that such an `id` column exist, we can try:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE t2.uID = t1.uID AND t2.id <> t1.id);
```

Comment: the earlier version works perfectly--many thanks